# how to make two arrays from text file which contains words

Tags: c++

I have a text file something like:

```
cat dog
mom dad
is have
black ears
!stop
blah blah blah
```

and I want to separate these text file words into two arrays, so i could have 2 arrays; one that contains

```
cat mom is black
```

and the other

```
dog dad have ears
```

I am wondering what should I do, cause I know how to make one long array but not how to make two
and also words will always be short - like not more than ten characters

Comment: But what have you tried?

Comment: It seems you want to read a line and if the line isn't `!stop` read two words from the line and insert them into different arrays. Seems straight forward...

Comment: This question is too broad because you are asking for other people to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only tricky part seems to be the termination, e.g., when there is just one word on the line. A simple approach would be to read lines and then decode them but, instead, *four* items could be read: between the first and the second item there should be no newline and there should be a newline after the second item:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::istream& noeol(std::istream& in) {
    for (int c; (c = in.peek()) != std::char_traits<char>::eof()
             && std::isspace(c); in.get()) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}

std::istream& eol(std::istream& in) {
    for (int c; (c = in.peek()) != std::char_traits<char>::eof()
             && std::isspace(c); in.get()) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            return in;
        }
    }
    in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return in;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("some.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> c0, c1;
    for (std::string s0, s1; in >> s0 >> noeol >> s1 >> eol; ) {
        c0.push_back(s0);
        c1.push_back(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious approach would seem to be something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> column1, column2;

std::ifstream in("filename.txt");

std::string a, b;

while (in >> a >> b) {
    column1.push_back(a);
    column2.push_back(b);
}
```

Comment: Which would, of course, produce a different result because it happily reads beyond `!stop` and would produce entries `!stop` and `blah` in the first array and `blah` `blah` in the second array. It seems, that could use a nice `end_of_line` manipulator ;)

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Of course -- while I'm fine with getting somebody started in at least sort of the right general direction, I'm not going to just complete their homework for them.